# Write an IP with Netmask (sed)

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a problem. I want to write an IP into a file with `sed`

```
newsource=1.2.3.4/24
sed -i 's/.*#source*/&\n'"$newsource"'/' file
```

`$newsource` is an IP, which CAN contain a net-mask `/24` or not. Right now the `sed` writes the full IP but not the `/24`. How can I change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you must either escape your `/`, or change the `sed` separator to something else:

## escape: `\/`

```
newsource=1.2.3.4\/24
sed -i 's/.*#source*/&\n'"$newsource"'/' file
```

or

## change `sed` separator to `~`

```
newsource=1.2.3.4/24
sed -i 's~.*#source*~&\n'"$newsource"'~' file
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sed -i 's|.*#source*|&\n'"${newsource}"'|' file
```

You could use \ to escape the / but since the path is stored in a variable it's probably easier to use a different separator.